# Do AVR delay functions (_delay_us() and _delay_ms()) use timers?

Tags: atmega328, timers, avr

I'm trying to determine if the AVR delay functions `_delay_us()` and `_delay_ms()` use timers in such a way that I can't use those timers for other functionality in my code. If so, what timer does it use?

For reference I'm using an Arduino Uno with ATmega328, but I imagine if it's an AVR function it must work similarly on other devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, these macros expand to calls to `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles()`,
which are compiled into delay loops. It should be noted that:

- the arguments to these macros should be compile-time constants, they
  can be floating point
- the macros are cycle-accurate, e.g. `_delay_us(0.125)` will take
  exactly two CPU cycles on an Uno
- whereas the *CPU time* used by the call is exactly what you ask for,
  the *physical time* will be larger if the call gets interrupted.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried I wouldn't be able to use one of the timers if I used the delay functions.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The long answer is that you can delay via timers, a little bit more painfully within the Arduino framework, or much more efficiently if you are willing to move outside of the arduino framework.

I wrote a set of systick clones for many of the popular 8bit mcus precisely for that.